# How to set the default position on page of the input type file picker HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When we use input tag with type="file", the default file picker in HTML will pop up on the top left position. How can I adjust it to any location such as at the center of browser for the default case?

Comment: Is that a correct duplicate? Since we want to center the file selector popup, not the file selector input button.

Comment: The file selection dialog position cannot be controlled through code.

Comment: Correct the duplicate question is different.

Answer (score 2):

The file picker dialog box is a native UI completely outside the control of the page author.

It may or may not appear in the top left depending on the browser / operating system / other factors.

You can't change that from your code.